# I can't insert List item to Object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, list, object

I want to insert List item to Object, this is the code:

```
public User login(String username, String password) {
    String stringQuery = "SELECT * FROM User U WHERE U.username = :username AND U.password = :password";
    Query query = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(stringQuery);
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("password", password);

    User user;

    List<User> userList = query.list();

    if (userList.size() == 0){
        return null;
    }

    user = (User) userList.get(0);

    return user;
}
```

And here User.class

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (id != user.id) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(user.password) : user.password != null) return false;
        if (username != null ? !username.equals(user.username) : user.username != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

In this line i get the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.project.server.base.User

```
user = (User) userList.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696), using [addEntity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addEntity%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
Query query = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(stringQuery);
query.addEntity(User.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you sure that this query will return unique result Use [uniqueResult()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult())

> Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query,
>   or null if the query returns no results.

```
public User login(String username, String password) {
    String stringQuery = "FROM User U WHERE U.username = :username AND U.password = :password";
    Query query = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createQuery(stringQuery);
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
    return (User)query.uniqueResult();
}
```

Or if you want to do it your way:-

```
public User login(String username, String password) {
    String stringQuery = "SELECT * FROM User U WHERE U.username = :username AND U.password = :password";
    Query query = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createQuery(stringQuery);
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
    List<User> userList = (ArrayList<User>)query.list();
    if (userList.size() == 0){
        return null;
    }
    return userList.get(0);
}
```

Comment: How is your second code any different from his code? (Excluding the fact that `query.list()` may not return an `ArrayList`, and your code will fail earlier than his)

Comment: Your code is correct like mine, but, i dont know why im having still the same error !

Comment: @peasantScript, this code is incorrect, Hibernate can't determine the result type using some magic (so it returns you an array of Objects - all the received columns), have you tried the solution I've described?

Comment: @peasantScript User mapped `@Entity`  use HQL instead of native query